# parse xml response with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

HI all,
I use jQuery to parse my xml responses.

I have this xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response status="ok">
  <client_id>185</client_id>
</response>
```

And i want to get "client_id" value.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First, make a request for the XML with $.get or however you want. 
Then:

```
clientID = $(myXML).find("client_id").text();
```

Comment: Smart! XML is a tag language.. yup!

Answer (score 39):

To fix the expected response data type to XML right in your request, set the `dataType` parameter to "xml". If you don't, jQuery uses the response headers to make a guess.

It is supported on the `$.ajax()` function as part of the `options` object, as well as on `$.get()` and `$.post()`:

```
jQuery.ajax( options )
jQuery.get( url, data, callback, type )
jQuery.post( url, data, callback, type )
```

So you could do this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "foo.aspx",
  data: {
    key: "value"
  },
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function (xml){
    var clientid = $(xml).find('client_id').first().text();
    alert(clientid);
  }   
});
```

---

Note that as of jQuery 1.5 you can use a nicer version of the above Ajax request:

```
$.get("foo.aspx", {
  key: "value"
})
.done(function (xml){
  var clientid = $(xml).find('client_id').first().text();
  alert(clientid);
});
```

Comment: Is this secure? You parse response content by jQuery and you're not sure about if it's correct or not.

Comment: @Artem If the response `Content-Type:` header type says `text/xml`, then jQuery will treat the response data as XML. If it says `application/json`, jQuery will treat the response as JSON. This works very well. I'm not sure what you mean by "secure".

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
$.ajax({ type: 'GET', url: 'test.xml', dataType: 'xml', success: function(xml){
            $('response', xml).each(function() {alert($(this).find('client_id').text());});         
            }});
```

Answer (score 2):

just to complement, i you use $.get:

```
$.get($('file.xml').val(),{  } , doSomethingWithData);
```

function doSomethingWithData(data) {

```
 $(data).find("marker").each(function() {


        var marker = $(this);


     alert(marker.attr("lat"));

 });
```

here tpicall used request.responseXML is the data in this case, and you have to encapsulate it in $(data) in order to work (this make me break the head about 3 hours ;S)

```
                     //    alert(markerh);

                }
```