# How do I convert XML nodes to string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I've such a xml string as following:

```
str = "<myxml><Node id="1" attr1="a" attr2="b" />
<Node id="2" attr1="a" attr2="b" /><Node id="3" attr1="a" attr2="b" />
<Node id="4" attr1="a" attr2="b" /></myxml>"

function returnNodeAsStr(str) {
...
...
}

if(returnNodeAsStr(str) == '<Node id="1" attr1="a" attr2="b" />') {
    alert("ok");
}
```

How to write a function to get the node as string?(make the alert execute)

Comment: if you are really using jquery, have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510995/parse-xml-response-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var str = '<myxml><Node id="1" attr1="a" attr2="b" /><Node id="2" attr1="a" attr2="b" /><Node id="3" attr1="a" attr2="b" /><Node id="4" attr1="a" attr2="b" /></myxml>';

function returnNodeAsStr(str) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(str),
        xml = $( xmlDoc ),
        item=[],
        results=[];
    $(xml).find('Node').each(function() {
        item.push("<Node");
        $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){
            item.push(attrib.name+"=\""+attrib.value+"\"");
        });
        item.push("/>");
        results.push(item.join(" "));
        item=[];
    });
    return results;
}

var result=returnNodeAsStr(str);
console.log(result);
/*
["<Node id="1" attr1="a" attr2="b" />", 
"<Node id="2" attr1="a" attr2="b" />", 
"<Node id="3" attr1="a" attr2="b" />", 
"<Node id="4" attr1="a" attr2="b" />"] 
*/

if(result[0] == '<Node id="1" attr1="a" attr2="b" />') {
    alert("ok");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regexps like this

```
var str='<myxml><Node id="1" attr1="a" attr2="b" /><Node id="2" attr1="a" attr2="b" /><Node id="3" attr1="a" attr2="b" /><Node id="4" attr1="a" attr2="b" /></myxml>';

var match = str.match(/<Node.*?\/>/g);

if(match.length){
   for(var i=0; i< match.length; i++)
      alert(match[i]);              
}
```

no additional dependencies required

P.S. you can even get individual attrs values via regexps, though it will become considerably hairier

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
var str = '<myxml><Node id="1" attr1="a" attr2="b" /><Node id="2" attr1="a" attr2="b" /><Node id="3" attr1="a" attr2="b" /><Node id="4" attr1="a" attr2="b" /></myxml>';​​​​​​​

var nodeArray = str.replace(/<\/?myxml>/g,'')    //removing root-> '<myxml>' tag
                .replace(/\/>\s*</g,'/>,<')      //replacing  '/><'  with '/>,<'
                .split(',');                     //spliting by comma  -------^
```

After this you will have an array of `Node` strings, and you can compare these elements with strings, e.g.:

```
if( nodeArray[0] == '<Node id="1" attr1="a" attr2="b" />'){
   //Do something
}
```