# How to validate youtube video ID with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, youtube

I wanna validate the youtube video id with JavaScript and make sure the video can be played normally(haven't been deleted)

I noticed many guys mentioned http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID, but the response data is formatted as xml. I tried to send jsonp request and got error messages coz the xml formatted.

Is there any way to do it without setting a proxy by some back-end codes??

Comment: You can process xml via Javascript very easy. For example see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510995/parse-xml-response-with-jquery

Comment: hmmmm, I need to send a jsonp request to youtube server, I will get error message if the data is not formatted as json object and all the codes below will be blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it's possible via JSONP: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json?hl=en

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads?v=2&alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos">
</script>
```

Comment: yeah, then I am thinking if there is a public url can be used for all the people without "users","GoogleDevelopers"? coz I can't use my private account.

Comment: Yes, you just have to add the `alt=json-in-script` and `callback=yourCallback` parameters to your previous URL: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_IDv=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=console.debug